# Rename data frame column when column name ends with a specific number

Tags: r, dataframe, rename

Found several questions regarding changing column names in a data frame, but didn't answer the issue I have.

I am reading in a number of excel files as data frames in a loop, doing some analysis with the data for each data frame and moving the next data frame. In each data frame where I need to rename a column whose name ends with, say for example, 00010. The position of the columns change in each file/data frame.

e.g. Imported column names are: `agency_id`, `site_no`, `datetime`, `tz_cd`, `11_00010`, `11_00010_cd`, `12_00030`,`12_00030_md`, ...

For my analysis, I need the following columns: `site_no`, `datetime`, `11_00010`, `12_00030`. I need to rename the column, `11_00010`, to temperature and column, `12_00030` to salinity. If they were in the same order I can easily rename the columns using `rename` in `plyr` or `colnames` or `names`. However, the sequence or order of the columns in each data frame is not same and the columns containing 00010 and 00030 may begin with different numbers, so the position of 00010 and 00030 in the column names is not always fixed. If it were renaming would be easier. Also, I do not need the columns whose name contain 00010 or 00030 but end with cd or md etc.

Would really appreciate any way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use `gsub`?

Assuming "x" to be your column names (normally accessed via `names(your-data-frame)`:

```
x <- c("agency_id", "site_no", "datetime", "tz_cd", "11_00010", 
       "11_00010_cd", "12_00030", "12_00030_md")

x <- gsub("11_00010", "temperature", x)
x <- gsub("12_00030", "salinity", x)
x
# [1] "agency_id"      "site_no"        "datetime"       "tz_cd"         
# [5] "temperature"    "temperature_cd" "salinity"       "salinity_md"
```

---

Judging by your comments, perhaps you're looking for something more like:

```
x <- c("agency_id", "site_no", "datetime", "tz_cd", "11_00010", 
       "11_00010_cd", "12_00030", "12_00030_md")

x[grep("_00010$", x)] <- "temperature"
x[grep("_00030$", x)] <- "salinity"
x
# [1] "agency_id"   "site_no"     "datetime"    "tz_cd"      
# [5] "temperature" "11_00010_cd" "salinity"    "12_00030_md"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I edited my question a little to add clarity. The column names 11_00010 and 12_00030 may not begin with 11 or 12 respectively. The constant logic, it seems, is that they end with 00010 and 00030.

Comment: I do not want to retain any part of the original name. I want to rename to columns, *_00010 and *_00030 to temperature and salinity respectively, where * stand for an arbitrary number.

Comment: There wouldn't be any duplicate column names. E.g. if there are 30-50 columns in the data frame, there will be only one column ending with 00010 and one column ending with 00030.

Comment: #Ananda Mahto: Your second answer is what I wanted. How do you replace the original column names in the data frame with x (in your second answer)?

Comment: @user2653586, that's already in my answer. Anywhere you see an "x" replace it with `names(your-data-frame)`.

Comment: Great. It works fine. Thanks a bunch. Did names(dataframe) <- x and it changed all the headers to what I wanted.